# SQLAlchemy generating query in loop with contains

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm building a web app in Flask that involves some SQLAlchemy.  I have a function "get_team()" that is driving me bonkers.

```
    def get_team(playerlist)
        cond = and_(*[Team.users.contains(p) for p in playerlist ])
        q = Team.query.filter(cond)
         ...
```

I keep getting the error:  "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'".  Here's what the models look like:

```
class Team(db.Model):                                                            
    __tablename__ = 'teams'                                                      

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)                                 
    users = association_proxy("user_associations", "user", creator=lambda u: Teaming(user=u))

    def __repr__(self):                                                          
        s = ""                                                                   
        for u in self.users:                                                     
            s = s + u.username + ", "                                            

        return "Team {tid}: {users_string}".format(tid = self.id, users_string=s)

class Teaming(db.Model):                                                         
    __tablename__ = 'teaming'                                                    

    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.id'), primary_key=True) 
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True) 

    user = db.relationship("User", backref="team_associations")                  
    team = db.relationship("Team", backref="user_associations")                  

    def __repr__(self):                                                          
        return "".format(uid = self.user_id, tid = self.team_id)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):                                                 
    __tablename__ = 'users'                                                      

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)                                 

    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)                    
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)                 
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))                                    
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)                             

    teams = association_proxy("team_associations", "team", creator = lambda t: Teaming(team=t))
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely cause is that `playerlist` is not a list of `User` instances, but some strings (maybe names). `contains` works only on model instances. If you would like to work with other attributes, then use `any`.

```
def get_team_of_players(playerlist):
    cond = and_(*[Team.users.contains(p) for p in playerlist])
    q = Team.query.filter(cond)
    return q

p1, p2 = db.session.query(User).get(1), db.session.query(User).get(2)
q = get_team_of_players([p1, p2]).all()


def get_team_of_usernames(usernames):
    cond = and_(*[Team.users.any(User.username == p) for p in usernames])
    q = Team.query.filter(cond)
    return q

p1, p2 = 'user1', 'user2'
q = get_team_of_usernames([p1, p2]).all()
```